# Django | Texto a mostrar en admin muestra id de choice y no texto

Tags: django, django-models

models.py me devuelve como return del id del choice, pero no el texto "Cuadro Fuerza" o "Cuadro comunicación". Si pongo get_tipo_instalacion_display devuelve error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si en vez de get_tipo_instalacion_display dejo sólo tipo_instalacion, de ve el id del choice y no el texto Cuadro Fuerza o Cuadro comunicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
class Instalacion(models.Model):
    INSTALLATION_TYPE_CHOICE = (
        ('0','Cuadro Fuerza'),
        ('1','Cuadro Comunicación'),
    )
    tipo_instalacion = models.CharField('TipoInstalacion', max_length=1, choices=INSTALLATION__TYPE_CHOICE,null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.tipo_instalacion)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay que añadir el siguiente código:

def **str**(self):
return str(self.get_tipo_instalacion_display())